# BluetoothAdvertisement - Watcher - How to unsubscribe from/filter out devices that were already received?

Tags: c#, .net, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am working with the Windows Software Development Kit (SDK) for Windows 10 to communicate with Bluetooth LE devices, iBeacons in this case, using Windows.Devices.Bluetooth.Advertisement library and I have the following question:

Is there a way to unsubscribe from/filter out devices that were already received by the watcher?

For example:

The BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher is started by the method Start()
Received event is triggered by a device and calls method OnAdvertisementReceived that will handle the event.
After handling the event, it filters out this device somehow and then the watcher received event will no longer be triggered by this device until the watcher is stopped.
Is there a way to achieve this?

I have checked the use of BluetoothLEAdvertisementFilter, but it seems you can only filter devices that match a certain criteria, not the other way round. In this case, I want to filter out already processed device(s) that match a certain criteria i.e. To no longer receive advertisements from a device with certain UUID, Major and Minor.

I have been using this Microsoft Sample for reference: [BluetoothAdvertisement sample](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/BluetoothAdvertisement)

Thanks

Comment: Create list of MAC addresses and put received devices into the list. next time check if device is in list and ignore it. Nothing can be simple.

Comment: Yes, I am already doing that using UUID+Major+Minor ids which is basically the Mac Adress for iBeacons, which It's working fine. But I was wondering if it would speed up the process to not receive advertisements of already processed beacons. If you are processing several iBeacons at the same time, the system will spend time looking up if the iBeacon received was already handled, what would be avoided if the system simply doesn't receive them anymore. Thanks @MikePetrichenko for your response.

Comment: UUID, Major and minor can be identical for several beacons. Its not the MAC (and even not closer to the MAC). Use real MAC for filtering. Its fast operating to look for In64 in array/list. Even if the system provided something like that (what is absolutely impossioble because a BLE device advertises a lot of different packets and how do you think to finlter it?) it will be implemented somthing like list of MACs.

Comment: I am filtering by MAC address now. I also improved other parts of the code and it seems to be faster now (Will have a better idea when users start testing) and more importantly, the check by Mac Address is more reliable than UUID+Major+Minor. Thanks @MikePetrichenko for the help and suggestions.